# class in lib directory still not recognized after adding to loads path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a directory structure in my libs directory:

```
  docx
    parser.rb
```

Some of its contents:

```
module Docx
  class Parser
  end
end
```

I want to add it to loads path, so that when I run rails console, it is loaded:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Unfortunately even after I run rails console, I get this error:

```
> Docx
NameError: uninitialized constant Docx
```

Despite the fact libs is in loads path:

```
2.1.2 :005 > ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
 => [#<Pathname:/Users/myuser/projects/docx_rails/lib>...
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the correct naming conventions?

In config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Then keep the right naming convention in lib.

In lib/moo.rb:

```
class Moo
end
```

in lib/moo/car.rb:

```
class Moo::Car
end
```

Comment: No I am not following that naming convention. Moo in my case is a module not a class. Does that matter?

Comment: My guess is it won't matter, but you'd have to try it to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

Lazy loading in Rails works - like many other features - only if you respect the "standards overy customization" philosophy.

In this case, to load the Docx module, you need to rename the file so that it is called docx.rb.

Although, it looks to me like you are trying to build a gem using the rails console.

I would recommend using the irb console (rails loads many libraries that you will need to explicitly require in your library - a fact you will never notice if you use the rails console).

Whenever you make code changes, you can use the load method to reload the code (unlike require, load forces the code to load again).

```
load 'docx.rb'
```